# WCF: How do I get the list of endpoints from ServiceHost?

Tags: .net, wcf, .net-3.0

I can add endpoints using `ServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint`. How do I get that list of endpoints back out?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Use `host.Description.Endpoints`